# How to parse a Json with days received from HTTP request into a list in Scala and Play Framework

Tags: json, scala, http, playframework, rest

I'm new to Scala and Play Framework.
I have a Json like this:

```
{
   "monday" : [],
   "tuesday" : [
       {
          "type" : "xyz",
          "value" : 1111
       },
       {
          "type" : "abc",
          "value" : 2222
       }
   ],
   .....
}
```

I'm trying to reading this Json in a list, or map, that contain, for every entry, a list of type/value.
I've defined a method that read the HTTP request body

```
def readJson() = Action { implicit request =>
      val body = request.body
      val jsonObject = body.asJson
}
```

I don't understand though how to continue, I've read the Play Framework documentation but I'm a bit lost.
Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: Go to this link you will get help : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson

Comment: I've checked that but the thing that I don't understand is that how can I read the Json if the label is different for every element, since it's the day of the week. Do I have to then read the 7 days on its own?

Comment: You need to implicit define `Format` for your case class representing request and use parser.json which implicitly takes it. See: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Choosing-an-explicit-body-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this

```
import play.api.libs.json._

final case class Task(
    `type`: String,
    value: Int
)
final case class Days(
    monday: List[Task],
    tuesday: List[Task]
)


implicit val ts = Json.format[Task]
implicit val da = Json.format[Days]


def readJson() = Action { implicit request =>
      
      val days:Option[Days] = request.body.asJson.getOrElse(Json.obj()).asOpt[Days]
  // .....
}
```

or instead of mapping json to Case class, you can use jsPath see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonCombinators

Comment: Thanks, I've used this:
`val body = request.body
    val days:Option[Days] = request.body.asJson.getOrElse(Json.obj()).asOpt[Days]
    days match {
      case Some(d) => Ok(views.html.hours(d.tuesday(0).value.toString))
    }`
and I can access the day as I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @guess85 please, accept and upvote answer if it was helpful,  this motivates contributors to publish answers.

Comment: Sorry, I've upvoted it but since my reputation is less than 15 it doesn't show. Yesterday I fogrot to accept it, I've just done it. Thanks again.